# Synchronous to asynchronous compiler for nodejs

Tags: node.js

Almost a year ago I saw a Node Js package that added some syntactic features into JavaScript to support asynchronous programming by writing code in synchronous style. It had a compiler that compiled the code into JavaScript asynchronous style.

Anyone knows of a package like this?

Answer (score 0):

Are you thinking of [IcedCoffeeScript](http://maxtaco.github.com/coffee-script/)?

You could also learn to use [async](https://github.com/caolan/async)'s `series` and `parallel` functions and write more synchronous-looking asynchronous code yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You may be thinking of [kaffeine](http://weepy.github.com/kaffeine/docs/unwrapping_async_calls.html) or [streamline.js](https://github.com/Sage/streamlinejs).